Mail Merge: Print two recipients in one page, each recipient unique per merge
I'm trying to build a mail merge that has two mails in one page for two different users. Lets say the Excel database looks like following:
 1. John
 2. Alice
 3. Bob
 4. Dave
 5. Chuck
 6. Carol

and Word template (one page) looks following:
Hello <<user>>, we are happy to announce ....
<<Next Record>>
Hello <<user>>, we are happy to announce ....

Using mail merge function in MS Word I'm getting results like following:
1st page looks great, next record does the trick here:
Hello John, we are happy to announce ....
Hello Alice, we are happy to announce ....

2nd page is, however, not ideal:
Hello Alice, we are happy to announce ...
Hello Bob, we are happy to announce ...

So basically I'm getting duplicates, I would like second page to start with Bob and Dave. I do not want duplicates. Each record should be unique. I have tried having two next records after first mail getting John and Bob on first page, Alice and Dave on second, but then there is Bob and Chuck which is again not what we wanted.
Does anyone knows what to do? My idea was to add another next record at the end of second mail but it looks like MS Word is ignoring that at the end.

Are you actually performing the merge? e.g. merging to print or merging to a new file? The behaviour you are seeiing suggests that you may just be previewing the merge.
